# Dynamic search using date

Tags: django

Can any one please help me i want to search my expenses income which is in my models.py using date wise dynamic search where  user will input date and he will see the result in template i dont know how to code that template ..I tried form but not working.. :(

my views.py

```
def date_page(request): 
    f_date = '2018-12-05'
    t_date = '2019-09-12'

    from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(f_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(t_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

    date_queryset = Add.objects.filter(date__range=(from_date, to_date))
    print (date_queryset)

    return render (request , 'date_page.html',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the date value as URL parameter and fetch it using [**`request.GET`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) as,

```
def date_page(request):
    f_date = request.GET.get("f_date")
    t_date = request.GET.get("t_date")

    date_queryset = Add.objects.filter(date__range=(f_date, t_date))
    print(date_queryset)

    return render(request, 'date_page.html', )
```

Example URL : **`/api/end-point/expenses/?f_date=2018-12-05&t_date=2019-09-12`**